# Outputs collection as DTO property without subquery using LINQ and Ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Consider I have the following classes

```
public class Root 
{
    public int RootId { get; set;}
}

public class Child 
{
     public int ChildId [ get; set; }
     public string ChildCode { get; set; }
     public int RootId { get; set; }
     public int ChildInfoId { get; set; }
}

public class ChildInfo
{
     public int ChildInfoId {get; set; }
     public string InfoName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'd like to fetch root and it's child using joins only. What should I put in `select` statement to get collection?

```
var query =
 from root in Context.Roots
 join child in Context.Childs on root.RootId equals child.RootId into childs
 from child in childs.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join childInfo in Context.ChildInfos on child.ChildInfoId equals childInfo.ChildInfoId
 select RootDto 
 {
    Id = root.Rootid,
    Childs = ????? [ ChildDto { ChildCode and InfoName from joined ChildInfo)
 }
```

Is it possible with LINQ and EF or Navigation properties are neccessary?

Comment: Do it in a second query.  You want to get a List() of childs and each select item is only one item.  In second query use a GroupBy the id to get the list.  If you want one query the add a parenthesis around current query : (from .........).GroupBy(..........

Comment: Without navigation properties you are effectively selecting a Cartesian between root and child. Your options are either to introduce navigation properties so that EF can work through the relationships to build the query for you, or add a group by on root in order to load children by root to select from. IMO navigation properties are the way to go. Using EF to merely write LINQ in place of SQL is really cutting the library short.

Comment: @StevePy yeah I know. But nav property is generting subqueries and that's why my main person responsible for DB performance is unhappy. I think that SP is way to go in that case - let him take care of optimizing query since I am not completely able to produce SQL he is expecting from me.

Comment: Or utilize a view.  EF's queries are quite efficient. Their SQL can be rather ugly to read for someone used to writing SQL but performance-wise they hold up quite well especially when you are leveraging `Select` to reduce your results to just the data you need. From there you capture the queries being run during normal operations and check execution plans for suggested indexes. DBAs and DB focused devs can be a bit critical of EF queries, but it helps if you keep them focused on real performance problems if they occur rather than just speculations based on what they see.

Comment: The trouble with Sprocs is that you have business concerns (the data your views etc/ need) now duplicated between C# and TSQL. To change functionality requires updating both. (Been there, done that with NHibernate and Sprocs when devs didn't understand how NH works. It's hell on moderate to large systems.)